# how to control Qt layout when shrinking the layed-out objects too much

Tags: qt, layout

I cannot wrap my head around how to setup the SizePolicy of a simple horizontal layout in Qt5.4, under "extreme" shrinking conditions.

The layout of objects looks like this:

[image]

The layoutSizeConstraint is set to "setFixedSize"
The layoutStretch for these 5 objects is : "1,1,1,1,1"

The object of interest is the QLineEdit at the right end of the layout. It has a minimum width of 200. Additionally the horizontal size policy is set to "Minimum" and the stretch factor is 2.

All objects on the left of the QLineEdit have a factor of 1 and a size policy of "preferred".

Unfortunately, when I shrink (horizontally) the horizontal layout (signified by the red box outline), part of the QLineEdit disappears as shown.

1) I would assume that resizing of the layout would keep all internal objects fully visible (is this a bug?)

2) since I have set a minimum size and minimum  sizePolicy for the lineEdit, I would expect that at extreme shrinking scenarios, the layout engine would make the minimum width requested by lineEdit available to it, while shrinking even more the rest of the layed-out objects. How can I actually manage that?